# Python: While loop will not terminate

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have read a lot of topics regarding while loops and I can't find one that tells me what I have done wrong with my own code.  I am doing the Learn Python the Hard Way and I wrote this code in order to satisfy the study drill #1 for exercise 33.  I cannot figure out why the loop won't terminate when I put in my raw data.

```
numbers = []

def number_uno(z):
    i = 0
    while i < z:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


print "Pick a random number: "
z = raw_input("> ")

number_uno(z)

print "Done"
```

Any ideas?  it just keeps adding 1 to "i" and will not stop printing.

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string.  when you pass it to your function, you're comparing an integer and a string.  Note that this behavior was deprecated in python3.x.  You can't compare integers with strings in python 3.x in this way.  (It'll raise a `TypeError`).

You can remedy this quite easily:

```
number_uno(int(z))
```

should run OK.

Comment: I wonder why it's even allowed in Python2 and what the result means.

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- in python2, the ordering is determined by object type, but is implementation dependent.  In other words `1 > "foo"` will give the same result as `100 > "bar"`, but what that result actually is isn't well defined.

Comment: In CPython 2.x, the default behavior when comparing objects of different types is to compare their types as strings. Thus all integers are less than all strings, because `"int" < "str"`. This was done to segregate the objects by type while sorting lists containing various types, but I don't believe other Python implementations are obliged to do the same.

Comment: Wow. I don't know what else to say :)

Comment: @kindall -- thanks for explaining the rational (and algorithm that cpython2.x uses).  I always wondered how it decided since it's not mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  I don't know why that didn't hit me!  Thanks a bunch for the prompt replies!

Comment: … and that's exactly why they took it out of Python 3, because it confuses people more often than it helps. If you really want the Python 2 behavior, you can always use, e.g., `key=lambda x: (type(x), x)`.